# How to replace part of path-to-file in a for...in loop using shell script on unix?

Tags: unix, for-in-loop

Need help big-time. I am totally stuck on this one. I am looping (recursively) through all the files in a directory and printing a list of files. Something like:

```
# srcDir="input received from command line"
# tgtDir="input received from command line"

for listItem in `find ${srcDir}`
do
    if [[ -f ${listItem} ]]
    then
        echo ${listItem} # **** what to put here ****
    fi
done
```

When printing the list, I want to replace the path of the file from the srcDir to tgtDir. Something like:

```
# let's assume that srcDir="/home/user"
# and tgtDir="/tmp/guest"
# srcDir has the following structure
file1.txt
dir1_1/file1a.txt
dir1_1/file1b.txt

# so the actual output of the script will be
/home/user/file1.txt
/home/user/dir1_1/file1a.txt
/home/user/dir1_1/file1b.txt

# but I want it to print as
/tmp/guest/file1.txt
/tmp/guest/dir1_1/file1a.txt
/tmp/guest/dir1_1/file1b.txt
```

I hope you got the idea. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for [bash string operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22429):

```
srcDir="/home/user"
tgtDir="/tmp/guest"
listItem="/home/user/file1.txt"
echo ${listItem/$srcDir/$tgtDir}
```